# HTML - How to stick an element on top of a mat-select scrollable list?

Tags: html, css

I have this mat-select with many optons in it so it becomes scrollable. I've implemented a search bar to filter the options, but if scrolled the input field gets hidden if going too low, just like all other content of the list. How can I make it stick to the top? I've already tried `position:absolute` but it doesn't work, it still gets scrolled away. I've also tried a different approach trying to make it always start from the top with disableOptionCentering but it doesn't work either.

HTML:

```
<div class="combo">
  <div>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="calendarfilter">
      <mat-label>Categoria Evento</mat-label>
      <mat-select (selectionChange)="filteredEvento.emit($event.value)" [ngModel]="tipieventi[0].id">
        <input class="filter" placeholder="Trova..." matInput (keyup)="onKey($event.target.value)">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let tipoevento of selectedTE" [value]="tipoevento.id">
          {{tipoevento.descrizione}}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.calendarfilter{
  width: 300px;
}
.combo{
  height: 70px;
}
.filter{
  width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried position:fixed;?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `position:sticky` and `top:0` :)

```css
.calendarfilter {
  width: 300px;
}

.combo {
  height: 70px;
}

.filter {
  width: 300px;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.white_space {
  background: palegreen;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="combo">
  <div>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="calendarfilter">
      <mat-label class="sticky">Categoria Evento</mat-label>
      <mat-select (selectionChange)="filteredEvento.emit($event.value)" [ngModel]="tipieventi[0].id">
        <input class="filter sticky" placeholder="Trova..." matInput (keyup)="onKey($event.target.value)">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let tipoevento of selectedTE" [value]="tipoevento.id">
          <div class="white_space"></div>
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</div>
```

---UPDATE---

Because I'm not sure if you can move out `<input class="filter" ...>` from `<mat-select>`

> I mean like this:
>
> ```
> <mat-form-field>
>   <mat-label></mat-label>
>   <input class="filter" placeholder="Trova..." matInput (keyup)="onKey($event.target.value)">
>   <mat-select></mat-select>
> </mat-form-field>
> ```

if you can, use this code:

```css
.combo {
  position: relative;
  height: 70px;
}

.filter {
  width: 300px;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 5px;
  bottom: 0;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16) 0px 1px 4px;
  background: #cfd8dc; /* you can change background color here */
}

.sticky>input {
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #cfd8dc;
}


/* you can delete this part */

body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: overlay;
}

.white_space {
  background: plum;
  height: 1000px;
}


/* you can delete this part */
```

```html
<div class="combo">
  <div>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="calendarfilter">
      <div class="sticky">
        <mat-label>Categoria Evento</mat-label>
        <input class="filter" placeholder="Trova..." matInput (keyup)="onKey($event.target.value)">
      </div>
      <mat-select (selectionChange)="filteredEvento.emit($event.value)" [ngModel]="tipieventi[0].id">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let tipoevento of selectedTE" [value]="tipoevento.id">
          <!-- you can deelete this part -->
          <div class="white_space"></div>
          <!-- you can deelete this part -->
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</div>
```

but if you `can't` and with moving out `<input class="filter" ...>` from `<mat-select>` your code doesn't work, you should use this one:

```css
.combo {
  position: relative;
  height: 70px;
}

.label_holder {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 10px 6px;
  height: 25px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 5px;
  background: #cfd8dc; /* you can change the background color here */
}

.filter_holder {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 25px;
  padding: 10px 10px 6px;
  border-radius: 0 5px 5px 0;
  margin-left: -10px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background: #cfd8dc; /* you can change the background color here */
}

.filter {
  width: 300px;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 5px;
  bottom: 0;
}

.sticky>input {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #cfd8dc;
}


/* delete this part */

body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-y: overlay;
}

.white_space {
  background: plum;
  height: 1000px;
}

/* delete this part */
```

```html
<div class="combo">
  <div>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="calendarfilter">
      <mat-label class="label_holder sticky">Categoria Evento</mat-label>
      <mat-select (selectionChange)="filteredEvento.emit($event.value)" [ngModel]="tipieventi[0].id">
        <div class="filter_holder sticky"><input class="filter" placeholder="Trova..." matInput (keyup)="onKey($event.target.value)"></div>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let tipoevento of selectedTE" [value]="tipoevento.id">
          <!-- delete this part -->
          <div class="white_space"></div>
          <!-- delete this part -->
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works but now all the options from the list are blank. Also I had to remove the whitespace because it was just a big green square that was covering everything.

Comment: ok apparently it was just a compilation error. Anyway it works! But as I am already here, may I ask if there's a way to make the search bar non-transparent? I thought about putting a white div between it and the list but I was looking for a simpler way

Comment: @LorenzoBertolaccini , I added the white_space to simulate scroll so you can scroll and see the result feel free to remove it, and about your question I updated the answer hope it helps.

Comment: No work, the background is still transparent. I managed to create a white div as a BG but I can't seem to be able to make it sticky. For some reason, if I use the sticky class on the div that contains the search bar, the sear bar is the one getting sticky while the div gets to scroll away.

Comment: By transparent you mean white? if it is white then by adding `background` property to the input you can change it's color,I'll update the answer again see if it's what you want

Answer (score 0):

To #Alireza's answer, if you would like, that the searchbar doesn't be at the absolut top, you can change the top.

e.g. `top: 5px`

You can also use the `position: fixed`

e.g. `position: fixed`
`top: 5px`
`left: 10px`
`right: 10px`

```css
.calendarfilter {
  width: 300px;
}

.combo {
  height: 70px;
}

.filter {
  width: 300px;
}

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 5px;
}

.white_space {
  background: palegreen;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="combo">
  <div>
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="calendarfilter">
      <mat-label class="sticky">Categoria Evento</mat-label>
      <mat-select (selectionChange)="filteredEvento.emit($event.value)" [ngModel]="tipieventi[0].id">
        <input class="filter sticky" placeholder="Trova..." matInput (keyup)="onKey($event.target.value)">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let tipoevento of selectedTE" [value]="tipoevento.id">
          <div class="white_space"></div>
        </mat-option>
      </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</div>
```